# Android 9 How to Enable CSS Color Module Level 4 Behavior?

Tags: android

In the [behavior changes for Android 9](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#hex-value-handling), it states:

> Apps that target Android 9 or higher must enable the draft CSS Color Module Level 4 behaviour for handling 4 and 8 hex digit CSS colors.

The docs link out to the [spec for CSS Color Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-color), but do not give any explanation of what actually needs to be changed within the app.

I am looking for an explanation of what needs to be done in order to enable this behavior, whether I need to change values in the app (e.g. colors.xml) resources vs just in WebView, and any other information that might be helpful in understanding what exactly this change entails

Comment: Definitely unclear... A comment on [Chromium issue 618472](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=618472) seems to contradict the note in the behavior changes for Android 9 you reference: "Yup, sorry, Toby probably didn't notice this as he's not CCed on the bug. Any app that *targets* P or later in its manifest can use 8-digit CSS colors, even if it's running on an earlier OS version." Testing the behavior when targeting API 28 seems warranted.

Comment: Sorry for the quick reply... but some quick digging into the web view initialization code in [WebViewChromium.java](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/android_webview/glue/java/src/com/android/webview/chromium/WebViewChromium.java?q=setcsshexalphacolorenabled&dr=C&l=214-217) appears to agree with the comment that it's simply based on targeting API 28 (again, contradictory to the note in the behavior changes for Android 9). If I get an opportunity to test and confirm, I'll promote these comments into an answer.